# Why do closed questions with rollbacks show up so strangely in the Reopen Queue?

Tags: support, review, revisions-list, vote-to-reopen, rollbacks

At present, [this Reopen queue entry](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/28005) shows up like this on the Revision tab:

> - Jan 8 at 16:47 - Rollback to [8142c784-73d6-4387-9fa2-366dec3a5762]
>
> *No changes to display.*
>
> [View this post's full revision history.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/43455/revisions)
>
> [meaning](/questions/tagged/meaning) [meaning-in-context](/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) [phrase-meaning](/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning) [lyrics](/questions/tagged/lyrics) <s>[song-lyrics](/questions/tagged/song-lyrics)</s>

Needless to say, this is rather disconcerting (since it shows something that seems to appear nowhere else in anything like that form), and somewhat less than helpful for the erstwhile reopen voter attempting to see what's been changed. What's up with that?

Comment: What's happening is that the GUID of the revision is showing as the default revision description in the queue. Why that's happening I don't know.

Comment: @Emrakul: The dupe (found in related questions, but only after actually asking :() suggests it's an aspect of the internal implementation being exposed, and that elsewhere this is covered with a user-friendly revision display. Whatever the case, it certainly seems this would be nice to get right.